# How to start apache2.4 service as administrator

Tags: windows, apache, apache2, odbc

I am trying make ODBC connection using Xampp.
When i run apache2.4 as service it runs with local user credentials and it shows access denied error. But when i run Xampp as admin and start it manually it works fine. So my question is how do i run apache2.4 service as administrator. P.S. I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Bring up the **Services** (*services.msc*) application. Find the Apache service and double click it.

Click "Log On" tab and click "This account:" and enter the credentials for your Administrator account.

---

**Alternatively**
Do the above but rather than the "Log On" tab, grab the *Path to the executable:* and navigate to its folder using Windows Explorer and right-click on the executable and click Properties and click Compatibility.

Make sure "Run this program as an administrator" is ticked and click OK.

---

You should be good to go!